# Covering Numeric Combinations

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I know this is a dupe but can't quite describe it correctly for the search.

What's it called when you can cover all combinations of a set by sequentially entering numbers?

For example, consider the set {1,2,3,4,5} and I want to cover all the 3-digit combinations with a minimal number *moves*.

1,2,3,4,5,1,3,2 ... would cover {1,2,3}, {2,3,4}, {3,4,5}, {4,5,1}, {5,1,3}, {1,3,2}, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called a [De Bruijn sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Permutations without repetitions

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a [(5,3) gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#n-ary_Gray_code).

Comment: Wait, nevermind, that would allow repetition.  I'll leave this answer for future googlers looking for exactly this, though.